# delta functions don't form a basis for function space if the set of the domain is infinite

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm studying for Linear Algebra and encountered this exercise, it seems intuitive but I can't pinpoint exactly why it's true.

K is any field.

S is any set.

Fun(S,K) is the vector space of all K-valued functions on S. (all maps f: S-> K)

Show that if a set $S$ is infinite, then the collection of delta functions 
$$[\delta_s]_{s \in S}$$ defined as a map $$S -> K$$ (and for $t \in S$):
$$t-> \begin{cases} 
      0 & t\neq s \\
      1 & t=s \\
   \end{cases}$$
does **not** span the vector space Fun(S,K) and cannot form a basis for it.

My progress/thoughts:
1. why wouldn't the collection of delta functions form a span if the set is infinite. You could still systematically define every single vector as a linear combination (unless linear combinations need to be finite?)

Comment: You are right that "linear combination" in a purely algebraic context means only _finite_ linear combinations. So the function that is $1$ everywhere is not a _finite_ linear combination of those "delta" functions, for $S$ infinite.

Comment: my question was not that clear, but this response was. Thanks again paul!